# Get an array of distinct values for a column from dojo/store

Tags: arrays, json, dojo

**My Scenario:**

This is my test data in JSON Array format:

```
var testDataObj = [
  { col1: 'p0',   col2: 1, tbl: 'p',   col3: '14/01/2013', col4:'BOB'},
  { col1: 'p1',   col2: 2, tbl: 'p',   col3: '14/01/2013', col4:'SANDY'},
  { col1: 'p2',   col2: 3, tbl: 'p',   col3: '14/01/2013', col4:'JASON'},
  { col1: 'p3',   col2: 4, tbl: 'p',   col3: '14/01/2013', col4:'JASON'},
  { col1: 'p4',   col2: 5, tbl: 'p',   col3: '14/01/2013', col4:'SANDY'},
];
```

I created an object of dojo/store/Memory as following:

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory"], function(Memory){
  var gctsTestStore = new Memory({data: testDataObj});
});
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to get an array of distinct values of column `col4`:

```
var distinctColumnValues=gctsTestStore.getDistinctValuesFromColumnName('col4');
//distinctColumnValues= ['BOB','SANDY','JASON']
```

**My Request:**

Currently, I am looping through JSON Array testDataObj to achieve the result, but I am exploring a more elegant solution using dojo/store's API.

I am using dojo/store/Memory here but I can also accept solution for other type of dojo/store.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. We need to see the code you're currently using; 2. We won't write code for you if you haven't tried it yourself.

Comment: My current workaround is looping through JSON array testDataObj to get an array of distinct values. I'm looking for a more elegant or built-in api in Dojo that does the job. I tried looking for it for 2 days, didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

There are no built in APIs for getting Distinct values from Memory Store.
You need to write you own method in Javascript for getting the distinct. Below is one way of writing it.

```
var unique = {};
var distinct = [];
for( var i in array ){
 if( typeof(unique[array[i].col4]) == "undefined"){
  distinct.push(array[i].col4);
 }
 unique[array[i].col4] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @frank, I wrote a js function to get the distinct values, but I think your function is shorter. I will try it out.